# Spring Boot org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 1. Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a problem about running some tests through JUnit in my Spring Boot application.

When I tried to run any test of repositorytest, I got the issue shown below.

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 1. Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
```

I also defined @Runwith annotation but it didn't help me fix my issue.

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

@DataJpaTest
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CategoryRepositoryTests {

    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Test
    public void givenCategoryObject_whenSave_thenReturnSavedCategory() {

        // given - precondition or setup
        Category category = Category.builder().name(CategoryType.COMIC.getValue()).build();

        // when -  action or the behaviour that we are going test
        Category savedCategory = categoryRepository.save(category);

        // then
        assertThat(savedCategory.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
        assertThat(savedCategory).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think it might be that @RequiredArgsConstructor try removing it

Comment: @Icarus After I removed it, I got another error ("this.categoryRepository" is null)

Comment: try adding @Autowire to categoryRepository

Comment: @Icarus I shared the solution after I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I defined `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` , the issue disappeared.

Here is the solution shown below.

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CategoryRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
}
```